# How to get value from edittext in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I have used grid view in my project

My activity layout file

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:visibility="visible"    >
    </GridView>
```

My grid layout(grid_change_prices.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
>
     <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cplabel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/cpprice"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/add_price"
       android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
       android:textSize="12dp"
       android:inputType="number" />
      </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Output from emulator
check this URL
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc6cs.png**

My code file

```
public void fillgrid(int categoryid,String car){
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
final DatabaseClass2 db = new DatabaseClass2(this);
    db.openDataBase();
Cursor c = db.getprice(categoryid); 
startManagingCursor(c);
String[] fromColumns = {"_id",DatabaseClass2.colPrice};
int[] toViews = {R.id.cplabel, R.id.cpprice};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.grid_change_prices, c, fromColumns, toViews);
        //c.moveToNext();
gridView.setAdapter(adapter); }
```

**Now my query is 
When i click modify button, I want to update my database with the new values
i tried to get values from edit text by using .gettext() . 
but it only returns value from first edittext**

**How i got the values from other edittexts, with the row id as well 
so that i update database with new price of same design..?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a GridView for such simple work?
better if you use ListView and it would be easier to populate the list and getting values from other EditText's.

I can give you an idea... just see this code what I'm doing in this :

```
public class RecordExpenseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>
    {

        Intent intent;
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> RecordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();           
        public RecordExpenseAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> RecordList) 
        {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, RecordList);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.RecordList = RecordList;
            this.intent = new Intent(context, ScanReceipt.class);
            //Log.d("ASD:","comp intialize");
       }    

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ImageHolder holder = null;

            try{


        if(row == null)
        {
        Log.d("ASD:","insdie getview");
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.categoryName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.date = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.amount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.record_rid = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ridRecord);     
        holder.cid=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.cid);
        holder.vendor=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.vendor);
        holder.description=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.attachURL=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.userFile);
        holder.attachImage=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.attachment);
        holder.scanReceipt = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        row.setTag(holder);
        holder.scanReceipt.setTag(position);

        holder.scanReceipt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    Log.e("Scan Receipt Button List", "1");
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                    Log.e("Scan Receipt Button List", "2");
                    int pos = (Integer) iv.getTag();
                    Log.e("Scan Receipt Button List", "3");
                    ScanReceipt.rid = RecordList.get(pos).get("rid").toString();
                    Log.e("Scan Receipt Button List", "4");
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    RecordExpenseAdapter.this.doIt();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error on click on Scan Receipt Button List", e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });

//      if(picture.get("userfile")=="no")
//      {
//          holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      }
        row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
        holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> picture = RecordList.get(position);

        holder.categoryName.setText(picture.get("category_name"));
        holder.date.setText(picture.get("date"));
        holder.amount.setText(picture.get("amount"));
        holder.record_rid.setText(picture.get("rid"));
        holder.cid.setText(picture.get("cid"));
        holder.vendor.setText(picture.get("vendor"));
        holder.description.setText(picture.get("description"));
        holder.attachURL.setText(picture.get("image"));

        Log.e("Record Expense Adapter 0 : IMAGE", picture.get("image").toString());
        Log.e("RID : " + position, picture.get("rid").toString());

    //  Log.e("error value", picture.get("userfile"));

        //Log.e("error value", "value is error");

//      if(picture.get("userfile")=="no")
//      {
//          holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
//      }
//          
//      else
//      {
//          holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
//      }
        if(picture.get("image").toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            holder.scanReceipt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.scanReceipt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.attachImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        return row; 
        }

public void doIt(){
    Log.e("Adapter 0", "In do It");

    context.startActivity(intent);
}

        static class ImageHolder
        {
                TextView categoryName;
                TextView date;
                TextView amount;
                TextView record_rid;
                TextView vendor;
                TextView cid;
                TextView description;
                TextView attachURL;             
                ImageView attachImage,scanReceipt;
        }

}
```

in above code, I have implemented the click listener on ImageView scanReceipt. It's the same imageview each time i.e. the same layout is inflated for each row, which means the same id is inflated for all the rows but still this click event will perform a different task for different row.

what you need to do is :  simply use the EditText as I'm using the ImageView. Implement the TextWatcher as I'm implementing the click listener.

you have to use custom list for that say this-

```
List<CustomClass> list = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
```

in this custom class, put the public variables so that you can access those by object of CustomClass and add that object to this above created list.

Once you get the values in this list, you can use it any way you want.

I hope it would help... :)

Comment: I changed from gridview to listView and populated the listview from database with cursor..
But now What i do,I didn't understand how to get the value of each Edittext with its rowId

Answer (score 0):

@Prakash
thanxx for idea dude

Now, I attached textwatcher to edittext field and managed to get rowid
with the help of this

```
price_text.setTag(c.getPosition());
```

And retreive that position in afterTextChanged

```
price_text.getTag()
```

But now how could i save that values Like you said in above post....

Comment: add the values in a arraylist of type class. this class would be a custom class which hold the two values : row id and text from that row.